# Does the developer payload work when the application in Alpha with test accounts?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to develop an android app with in-app billing. Everything seems to be working, except I am not getting back my developer payload.

This is how I am setting the data:

```
protected void purchaseItemSubs(String sku, String data) {

    billingHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow(this, sku, 123, this, data);

}
```

Comment: Where do you fill in the payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work in test. The reason I was not seeing anything was because I had called this function before with the payload being empty and Google associated that empty field with my test account till the next subscription cycle.